# What do the sequence of instructions in 8051 assembler do?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I have this code in 8051 assembler :

```
    MOV A,#04H
    RL A
    MOVC A,@A+PC
    SJMP Cont
Cont:   DB 10H, 20H, 30H, 40H, 50H, 60H, 70H, 80H
```

The question is that what is value of A after these instructions are executed; the answer was that A holds the value (A)=70H.

I have searched about MOV and RL instructions and I understood,but it is unclear to me,what do the rest of instructions and how did we get the value of register A?

Comment: What processor is this code for?

Comment: 8051 microprocessor

Answer (score 2):

[`MOVC A, @A+PC`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_movc.htm) moves 8-bit of data from the program memory (*MOVC* stands for "MOVe Code" or similar) at the address given by *A*+*PC* and stores it into the accumulator.
The presence of the `@` is eloquent, it is used to denote a [register indirect addressing mode](http://www.circuitstoday.com/8051-addressing-modes#register-indirect), the full expression `@A+PC` specify that it is actually an [indexed addressing mode](http://www.circuitstoday.com/8051-addressing-modes#indexed).
Note that:

1. The `PC` has already been incremented by the time it is used to do the memory access.
   Since `MOVC A, @A+PC` is 1 byte long, its semantic is:

   ```
   PC = PC + 1
   A = (A+PC)
   ```
2. In the symbolic expression `@A+PC`, the `@` is meant to have *less* precedence than the `+`, so it should be understood as `@(A+PC)`.

[`SJMP`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_sjmp.htm) is a *Short JuMP* and it simply execution to the target specified as the operand.

[`MOV A, #04H`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_mov.htm) moves the value 04h into `A`.
Here the symbol "#" denotes [immediate addressing mode](http://www.circuitstoday.com/8051-addressing-modes#immediate).

[`RL A`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_rl.htm) simply rotate right `A` by one position.

---

Let's assume the code starts at *X*, then

```
Address   Data     Instruction        State before         State after             Description
X + 00  : 74 04  : MOV A, #04       : A = ?  PC = X        : A = 4  PC = X + 02    Set A to 4 
X + 02  : 23     : RL A             : A = 4  PC = X + 02   : A = 8  PC = X + 03    Rotate left 4 = 0000 0100 -> 0000 1000 = 8, now A is 8
X + 03  : 83     : MOVC A, @A+PC    : A = 8  PC = X + 03   : A = 70 PC = X + 04    Read from memory A+PC, A = MEM[A + PC after] = MEM[8 + X + 04] = MEM[X + 0C] = 70
X + 04  : 80 00  : SJMP X + 06      : A = 70 PC = X + 04   : A = 70 PC = X + 06    Goto X + 06, PC <- X + 06
X + 06  : 10
X + 07  : 20
X + 08  : 30
X + 09  : 40
X + 0A  : 50
X + 0B  : 60
X + 0C  : 70
X + 0D  : 80
```

Simply put, when `MOVC A, @A+PC` is executed, a byte is read from the address of the next instruction added by 8 (the value in `A`).
Since `SJMP`, the next instruction, is 1 byte long, it is like reading 7 bytes from `Cont`.
The seventh item of `Cont` is 70h.